# What is Mathematical Formula behind Private Key and Address?

Tags: wallet, seed

I understand that the Private Key and Address pair is generated from the Seed + index number.  Is there anywhere where I can find the mathematical formula beside decoding the wallet code ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the entry point of generating a new address in e.g. the JS client library iota.lib.js found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/5e1f76faae29a0eb9251187678ed249742e5e4f0/lib/api/api.js). For more details you have to look into the Signing class found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/5e1f76faae29a0eb9251187678ed249742e5e4f0/lib/crypto/signing/signing.js).

The following code snippet is from the first linked class.

```
/**
*   Generates a new address
*
*   @method newAddress
*   @param      {string} seed
*   @param      {int} index
*   @param      {int} security      Security level of the private key
*   @param      {bool} checksum
*   @returns    {string} address     Transaction objects
**/
api.prototype._newAddress = function(seed, index, security, checksum) {

    var key = Signing.key(Converter.trits(seed), index, security);
    var digests = Signing.digests(key);
    var addressTrits = Signing.address(digests);
    var address = Converter.trytes(addressTrits)

    if (checksum) {
        address = Utils.addChecksum(address);
    }

    return address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The private/public keypair is computed by an algorithm. The algorithm in the wallet's code is the formula. Don't expect to find something different than this algorithm.